# What happens to a blocked Facebook account's email address?

Tags: facebook

What happens to a blocked Facebook account's email address?

Comment: Am I the first one that doesn't understand what you're asking?

Comment: @drachenstern Nope! @ilhan, blocked by whom: Facebook or by another user? If blocked by Facebook, presumably the user's email address gets blacklisted. Another user? Probably nothing.

Comment: i was blocked by Facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not usable in future accounts. You can use one Facebook account per email address.
I cannot remember the exact actions that occur (happened to someone I know a few years back) but a notification appears if one tries to associate it with a next account.
You would have to put forward an appeal (as he did) to Facebook.

See the [Facebook Help Disabled](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=1048) Section.
Here is the [form](http://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=disabled) for disabled accounts.